# CSS Icon Hover creating a box

Tags: css

I currently have a an icon tag and I am trying to style the `:hover` for the icon. It is from `font-awesome` library. My css is pretty straight forward.

```
i:hover {
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When I hover over my icon, I would like only the icon itself to have the hover effect rather than the bounding-box around my icon. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Do you want to turn the icon itself white on hover? If so, try `color: white`.

Comment: Can you create a working code snippet or JSFiddle and add it to your question?

Comment: You need to specify the class of the icon, not the `i` tag. For example, `.fa-flag:hover { color:white; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
i{
color:yellow;
font-size:22px;
}
a:hover .fa-google{
color:red;
}
.fa-facebook-square:hover{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
If its inside an element

<br>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google"></i> Hover Here</a>
<br>
Without another element
<br>
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>&nbsp;Hover the Icon
```